# UpdatePanel cannot set style

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax

I have an update panel on my aspx page which does not have a style property or attribute which you can use to override the style.  I know this is how it is designed so that is not the issue.  From looking online most resources have said that simply putting a div around the update panel and setting the style at that level will take care of the issue.  However a central div is created by Visual Studio which is stopping me from seeing my content.

*ASPX Code*

```
<div style="height:100%;width:100%;overflow:auto;padding-right:16px;" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="pdfPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" EnableViewState="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="pdfFrame" runat="server" style="height:100%;width:100%;overflow:auto;padding-right:16px;">
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

*How HTML is rendered*

```
<div style="height:100%;width:100%;overflow:auto;padding-right:16px;">
   <div id="ctl00_body_pdfPanel">
      <div id="ctl00_body_pdfFrame" style="height:100%;width:100%;overflow:auto;padding-right:16px;">
         <!-- Actual content here -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem is the pdfPanel which is being created has no style and is causing my inner div not to be displayed.  When I copy the style using Firebug from either of the other two controls then it becomes visible.

Comment: I think there's something we're missing because that HTML seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/BaTuj/

Comment: So you want all children of the first div to inherit the style?

Comment: Just throwing it out there because, but would it be possible to just set the inner div on the outside of the update panel? The code doesn't seem to suggest that would be a problem... if you keep having problems and don't want to waste time.

Comment: Yes @TheGeekYouNeed I want the children of the first div to inherit its style I was just experimenting with different things which is why the inner most div also has style set.  It shouldn't need it and should only be set in the outermost div.

Comment: @James Johnson the innermost div needs to be inside the update panel because there is logic happening in the code-behind to update the contents of that div and then refresh the update panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4.0 you can set ClientIDMode="Static" and it will give you the ID you set on the updatepanel itself.

Comment: I'll give this a try when I'm in the office again because we are using .NET 4.0

Comment: I set the div inside of the updatepanel to have ClientIDMode="Static" but this didn't resolve the error.  I believe this is occurring due to some strange html behavior elsewhere on the page because when I extracted the snippet in my original post into a stand-alone html then it was rendering fine.